# remove doublequote in read csv in r

Tags: r, double-quotes

data contain double quotes, is there any effective way to remove

> [Original german credit .csv data set given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/130cj.png)

> 

```
GermanCredit <- read.csv("D:/R Statistics/GermanCredit/germancredit.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, sep = "," , quote = "")
```

resulting as follow:

> [read.csv with quote argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/130cj.png)

> 

avoid to specify the quote argument

```
germancredit <- read.csv("D:/R Statistics/GermanCredit/germancredit.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, sep = ",")
```

result the following:

> [read.csv without quote argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/130cj.png)

> 

tried to use read.table

```
German_Credit <- read.table("D:/R Statistics/GermanCredit/germancredit.csv", quote = NULL, header = T, sep = ",")
```

try fread function from readr

```
dput(readLines("D:/R Statistics/GermanCredit/germancredit.csv", n = 10))
```

> c(""""status"",""duration"",""credit_history"",""purpose"",""amount"",""savings"",""employment_duration"",""installment_rate"",""personal_status_sex"",""other_debtors"",""present_residence"",""property"",""age"",""other_installment_plans"",""housing"",""number_credits"",""job"",""people_liable"",""telephone"",""foreign_worker"",""credit_risk"""",
> """"... < 100 DM"",6,""critical account/other credits
> existing"",""domestic appliances"",1169,""unknown/no savings
> account"",""... >= 7 years"",4,""male :
> single"",""none"",4,""real
> estate"",67,""none"",""own"",2,""skilled
> employee/official"",1,""yes"",""yes"",1"",  """"0 <= ...
> < 200 DM"",48,""existing credits paid back duly till
> now"",""domestic appliances"",5951,""... < 100 DM"",""1 <=
> ... < 4 years"",2,""female :
> divorced/separated/married"",""none"",2,""real
> estate"",22,""none"",""own"",1,""skilled
> employee/official"",1,""no"",""yes"",0"",  """"no
> checking account"",12,""critical account/other credits
> existing"",""retraining"",2096,""... < 100 DM"",""4 <= ...
> < 7 years"",2,""male : single"",""none"",3,""real
> estate"",49,""none"",""own"",1,""unskilled -
> resident"",2,""no"",""yes"",1"",  """"... < 100
> DM"",42,""existing credits paid back duly till
> now"",""radio/television"",7882,""... < 100 DM"",""4 <=
> ... < 7 years"",2,""male :
> single"",""guarantor"",4,""building society savings
> agreement/life insurance"",45,""none"",""for
> free"",1,""skilled
> employee/official"",2,""no"",""yes"",1"",  """"... < 100
> DM"",24,""delay in paying off in the past"",""car
> (new)"",4870,""... < 100 DM"",""1 <= ... < 4
> years"",3,""male : single"",""none"",4,""unknown/no
> property"",53,""none"",""for free"",2,""skilled
> employee/official"",2,""no"",""yes"",0"",  """"no
> checking account"",36,""existing credits paid back duly till
> now"",""retraining"",9055,""unknown/no savings
> account"",""1 <= ... < 4 years"",2,""male :
> single"",""none"",4,""unknown/no
> property"",35,""none"",""for free"",1,""unskilled -
> resident"",2,""yes"",""yes"",1"",  """"no checking
> account"",24,""existing credits paid back duly till
> now"",""radio/television"",2835,""500 <= ... < 1000
> DM"",""... >= 7 years"",3,""male :
> single"",""none"",4,""building society savings agreement/life
> insurance"",53,""none"",""own"",1,""skilled
> employee/official"",1,""no"",""yes"",1"",  """"0 <= ...
> < 200 DM"",36,""existing credits paid back duly till
> now"",""car (used)"",6948,""... < 100 DM"",""1 <= ... < 4
> years"",2,""male : single"",""none"",2,""car or
> other"",35,""none"",""rent"",1,""management/self-employed/highly
> qualified employee/officer"",1,""yes"",""yes"",1"",
> """"no checking account"",12,""existing credits paid back duly
> till now"",""domestic appliances"",3059,""... >= 1000
> DM"",""4 <= ... < 7 years"",2,""male :
> divorced/separated"",""none"",4,""real
> estate"",61,""none"",""own"",1,""unskilled -
> resident"",1,""no"",""yes"",1"" )

Comment: You may want to use `fread` from `data.table` as `GermanCredit <- fread("D:/R Statistics/GermanCredit/germancredit.csv")`. `fread` is much more powerful than `read.csv` for unusual format (and much more efficient).

Comment: How about specifying `quote = "\"\""` in `read.csv`?

Comment: @ytu that is the default; and according to the second example that also didn't work.

Comment: This will be almost impossible to answer without example data. Can you do a `dput(readLines("D:/R Statistics/GermanCredit/germancredit.csv", n = 10))` and add the output to your question?

Comment: @JanvanderLaan the default is `"\""`, not `"\"\""`.

Comment: @ytu you are right. Sorry misread the quoted-escaped-quotes :-s

Comment: @DJack in first line of my last paragraf i already mention that fread function also make no difference.

Comment: @ytu thankyou very much but it also make no difference

Comment: @JanvanderLaan did you mean the following, see above

Answer (score 1):

There are two strange things in your file

- The file uses double double quotes `""`
- The lines in you file are also quoted

`"""a"",1"
  """b"",2"`

This could be because your file was a csv file that was wrongly read (e.g. by using the wrong type of separators such as ';') which was then written away as a csv file.

First removing the outer quotes and then using double double quotes as quotes (as suggested by @ytu) seems to work:

`lines <- readLines("<yourfile>")
lines <- gsub('(^"|"$)', "", lines)
read.csv(textConnection(lines), quote = '""')`